# Merge into throws foreign key conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is part of my SQL statement:

```
MERGE INTO Scyk.dbo.Threads AS d
USING (SELECT Id,Question,QuestionTitle, Answer, Category FROM Homework.dbo.Zadanes) AS s
ON 1 = 2 
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (CurrentValue, NumberOfPosts, TotalValue, Views, Title, DateCreated, LastPostAuthor, LastPostDateTime, IsDeleted, Restricted, RestrictWrite, Sticked, CategoryName, AuthorUserName)
      VALUES (0, 2, 0, 0, s.QuestionTitle, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'zadania', DATEADD(second, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0, 0, 0, 0, s.Category, 'zadania')
```

This is the error that I get:

> The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Threads_dbo.Categories_CategoryName". The conflict occurred in database "Scyk", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Name'.

So the first thing I did, is that I checked for foreign key integrity:

```
SELECT Distinct(Category) FROM [Homework].[dbo].[Zadanes]
where not exists
(select distinct(Name) from Scyk.dbo.Categories)
```

But this returned nothing, and that means that foreign keys are good. So what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

You should just stop using `MERGE`, IMHO, and just use a normal `INSERT`. What is `MERGE` buying you here?

There are at least 15 bugs that remain unfixed in some or all supported versions of SQL Server:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

It sounds like [this is the one causing your issue](http://web.archive.org/web/20131030105705/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/685800/parameterized-delete-and-merge-allow-foreign-key-constraint-violations), and it has been closed as Won't Fix. The [last one may resolve your issue](http://web.archive.org/web/20100501071937/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/357419/merge-statement-bypasses-referential-integrity) ([get the fix from KB #956718](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=956718)), but somehow I doubt it. Even if it does, then you may be affected by one of the other 14 listed there (or another that has yet to be discovered). Sadly, this is a case of releasing a half-finished feature with minimal testing and then ignoring it for 3+ releases.

If you want to check the foreign key, your query should probably look like this:

```
SELECT Distinct(Category) FROM [Homework].[dbo].[Zadanes] AS z
where not exists
(select 1 from Scyk.dbo.Categories AS c WHERE c.name = z.Category);
```

Though it's odd that you have a foreign key on a name rather than, say, a CategoryID. What happens when the name changes? Do you have cascade options set? How much space are you wasting by repeating `'Electronics'` or longer category names in every row in `Zadanes`?

Comment: Believe me, I would love to. But I need to split data from one table into two others, and do few magic tricks with ID's on the way. And do that at least few thousand times. Now I am trying to disable foreign key checks and as far it is doing good for me.

Comment: @ojek ...until the next bug hits you. Also, how are you avoiding race conditions? I notice your target table doesn't have a HOLDLOCK hint... so is this transaction serializable?

Comment: No, I am simply disabling FK checks, since this is one-time thing, it does it for me.

Comment: @ojek perhaps you are not familiar with race conditions or concurrency. Is it possible for two users to run this statement at the same time?

Comment: The bug in this case may well be at the OP's end. Their `EXISTS` query isn't correlated so doesn't check what they think it is checking.

Answer (score 5):

What is going on is that your query says

Select any categories from `Homework.dbo.Zadanes` but only if there are no rows in `Scyk.dbo.Categories`.

Presumably there are rows in the latter table and therefore your query returned nothing.

Try

```
SELECT z.Category 
  FROM [Homework].[dbo].[Zadanes] z LEFT OUTER JOIN
       [Scyk].[dbo].[Categories] c
    ON z.Category = c.Name
 WHERE c.Name IS NULL
 GROUP BY z.Category
```

Also, unless you're using the `OUTPUT` clause to remap a bunch of IDs at once, there is no reason to use `MERGE` in place of `INSERT`.