# Is there a way of forcing sql INSERT or disabling foreign key check?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just found out a SQL Server bug (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819139/merge-into-throws-foreign-key-conflict)). Now I am wondering, if there is any possibility of forcing an `INSERT` statement without performing foreign key checks? Like disabling this checks server-wide for few minutes, or somehow disabling (not deleting) FK's on specific tables?

Comment: dont know why people down vote such a question ? what is wrong with it ?

Comment: [Well, the other answer, of course, is to stop using MERGE. Since that is not the only bug...](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Well your "check" in the linked question fails to correlate the `EXISTS` sub query so I'm not particularly convinced you've come across one of the issues with `MERGE`. Probably you are just trying to insert invalid data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Drop Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_ConstraintName
```

Drop the constraint once you have done the operation then create it again.

**Disable Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_Constraint_Name
```

**Enable Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
CHECK CONSTRAINT fk_Constraint_Name
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to delete those FK's, it will cause even more troubles.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE [schema].[table] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE [schema].[table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]
```

However, this results in your FK being not trusted, and when you re-enable the constraint it will take time to re-validate it.

Answer (score 3):

Check **[Disable Foreign Key Constraints with INSERT and UPDATE Statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175041.aspx)**:

> 1. To disable a foreign key constraint for INSERT and UPDATE statements
> 2. In Object Explorer, expand the table with the constraint and then
>      expand the Keys folder.
> 3. Right-click the constraint and select Modify.
> 4. In the grid under Table Designer, click Enforce Foreign Key
>      Constraint and select No from the drop-down menu.
> 5. Click Close.

or simple use this command:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_ConstraintName
```